# Different fancyref strings for different reference targets?

Tags: cross-referencing, fancyref

I use `fancyref` with the default prefixes (`chap:`, `fig:` and so on). I'm not entirely happy with the way the references are generated when the referenced object is on a different page. For tables and figures, the package generates something like *Abbildung 42 auf Seite 84* (figure 42 on page 84), which is acceptable. When referring to an entire chapter, the package uses the same text (*Kapitel 4 auf Seite 50*). In my opinion, that isn't entirely correct -- the chapter is not placed on page 50, it starts on page 50 and may stretch across any number of pages. I'd rather like the `\fref{}` command to use a different text when referring to chapters and parts, like *Kapitel 4 **ab** Seite 50*. At the same time, the references to figures and tables should not change. Is this possible?

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[german]{fancyref}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Einleitung}
\label{sec:A}
%\usepackage{graphics} is needed for \includegraphics
\begin{figure}[htp]
  Ze Figure
  \caption{A Figure}
  \label{fig:Foo}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{Überleitung}
\label{sec:B}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{Weiterleitung}
Wie in \fref{sec:A} bereits erw"ahnt\ldots
% This reads "auf Seite 1", should be "ab Seite 1"

Wie in \fref{fig:Foo} zu erkennen ist\ldots
% This reads "auf Seite 1", which is acceptable and should not be changed

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `vario` format for cross-references to sections so that it matches the `plain` one.

For example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[german]{fancyref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\frefformat{vario}{\fancyrefseclabelprefix}{%
      \frefsecname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}
\Frefformat{vario}{\fancyrefseclabelprefix}{%
      \Frefsecname\fancyrefdefaultspacing#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Einleitung}
\label{sec:A}
%\usepackage{graphics} is needed for \includegraphics
\begin{figure}[htp]
  Ze Figure
  \caption{A Figure}
  \label{fig:Foo}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{Überleitung}
\label{sec:B}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{Weiterleitung}
Wie in \fref{sec:A} bereits erw"ahnt\ldots
% This reads "auf Seite 1", should be "ab Seite 1"

Wie in \fref{fig:Foo} zu erkennen ist\ldots
% This reads "auf Seite 1", which is acceptable and should not be changed

\end{document}
```

produces the desired output, if I've understood your question correctly:

[image: plainer section references and fancier figure ones]